# spring mvc- form submit back button

Tags: spring, jsp, model-view-controller, submit

I  have a simple jsp form (page1.jsp)that allows the user to enter a bunch of textboxes. The submit button posts the form and displays page2
 On Page2- there is a tab called Page1- on clicking this tab, the user should be able to view page1 with all the information that he entered, so that he can edit it ,if he chooses to.

I have my controller set up for the first part page1- page2, working correctly.
However I am not sure how to implement the second part page2 ->page 1. I am unable to show the filled out form from the previous page.

I am not very proficient in Spring MVC and would appreciate some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Will it be ok to store the data in a global variable in controller and make a bean for the same with Request scope as done in this link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137152/store-temporary-data-in-a-spring-controller>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using two approaches . if you wish to use `@ModelAttribute` annotation and `spring:form` tags. you can use the form backing option to remember the values in the page.

1. [Spring MVC
   example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/spring-mvc-form-tutorial.html)
2. [Spring Form handling](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-form-handling/)

or you can do them in the native session handling .put your data to the session and then retrieve them when you go the prev page

Hope this helps !