# Adding back button to JSP to go back to previously generated page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

i have 3 jsp's-- **a.jsp**, **b.jsp** & **c.jsp**

In a.jsp there are many hyperlinks which takes user to b.jsp but each time data is dynamically fetched from database to be displayed on b.jsp according to the hyperlink selected.

Now all the data on b.jsp is in form of hyperlinks as well which takes me to c.jsp. c.jsp page is common for all the data(it does not depend upon the hyperlink selected in a.jsp or b.jsp). example-- c.jsp is a thankyou page.

I wanted to add **a back button in c.jsp** such that when a user clicks that button then he should be **redirected to b.jsp** having the previously generated dynamic data according to the hyperlink selected in a.jsp.

what should I do??

Comment: why you think you should do? what have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526104/3959856