# Store temporary data in a Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm wondering if I could store temporary data in a class attribute of a `Controller`.
My doubt is about the concurrency calls. Let us, for example, consider the following code:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    private final HashMap<Integer, Test> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, Test>();

    @RequestMapping(value = "test")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Test> test() {
        List<Test> list = new ArrayList<Test>();
        for (final OtherTest otherTest : otherService.getAll()) {
            Integer key = otherTest.getId();
            final Test t;
            if(testMap.containsKey(key)) {
                t = testMap.get(key);
            } else {
                t = testService.getByOtherTestId(key);
            }
            list.add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that `Controllers` are `Beans`, and I know that `Beans` are `Singleton`, so:

What happen if two users call the `test` method at the same time?
Each one of them read/write the same `testMap` object?
When the `testMap` object lose its scope and will be re-instantiated?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for testing purposes, or are you planning to use such an in-memory solution in production?

Comment: I'm gonna to use it in production... but I'm beginning to think that I need to instantiate a new `HashMap` in any `RequestMapping` method and pass it through any method. I'd like to have a class attribute to avoid to pass it to any method.

Comment: It should be a kind of cache, because I need the same information in several parts, and each time I get it from the database, so I'd like to have an `HashMap` in order to get that information faster.

Comment: All request will share the `testMap`, and it's well known that `HashMap` is not thread safe. Beside your `test()` method is not thread safe too.  The `testMap` will only be destroyed when spring framework destroyed.

Comment: You could use a session-scoped bean (@Scope) and let Spring autowire this bean into your controller, if your usecase requirements are per session.

Comment: @Kirinya thanks, this seems to be the cleanest solution. my scope bean should be per request, can I use the annotation `@RequestScope`?

Comment: I have not used @RequestScope, but from the documentation it seems fine to me.

Comment: I'll do some tests, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the two requests would manipulate the same `testMap` object. If you want to create a new `Map` for every request you can create a bean for it in one of your configuration classes:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope // or @Scope("request")
public Map<Integer, Test> testMap() {
    return new HashMap<>();
}
```

and autowire it in your controller:

```
@Autowired
private Map<Integer, Test> testMap;
```