# Store Data in Spring API

Tags: java, spring, datastore

I have a spring boot API and I have a case where I need to store some data to be used later in the process. When I use Atomic values or Concurrent Hash maps, the data is eventually overridden by each thread created by each new request. Unfortunately, I can not use the local/session storage in the browser. Is there any other way to store this data? Would it be wise to store that data in the DB for the duration of the session and delete it?

Comment: How are you storing the data? In a separate bean? What's the scope of the bean where your Atomics or Maps are?

Comment: I am currently storing them as global fields in the serviceImpl class. Should I create a Bean and a configuration for it?

Comment: I'd suggest only a `@Component @Scope("singleton")` bean and autowire it wherever you need it. Formally speaking, you do seem to need a database, an in-memory one like H2 or Redis if you need top speed, but if that's too complicated for whatever you are using, a singleton should be enough. Give it a go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try creating a bean first and see what happens.

Comment: It should be possible to declare a HashMap in your controller class (a bean) to achieve the same result. But then depending on your use case, mainly if different requests are expected to manipulate the same data, in that case this solution is not thread safe and you should look into properly scoping this data storing bean `@Scope("session")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store temporary data in a Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137152/store-temporary-data-in-a-spring-controller)

Comment: Unfortunately, using a bean with a singleton did not work for me. In my case, "session" would not work as well. I will probably end up using an in-memory.  Thank you all for your support.